# Why does my UIView draw as a white rectangle?

Tags: swift3

I trying to save my view (red view) to device's Photo Library, but after saving it have white color.

```
func saveViewToImage()
{
    redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: redView.frame.size)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    redView.draw(rect)
    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(resultImage!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Why?

Comment: This is a good question. I think it might help other people with the same problem if you changed the title to something like "Why does my UIView draw as a white rectangle?" since it doesn't really have anything to do with saving to the photo album.

Comment: Good point. Thank you. Renamed topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIView` `draw(_ rect:)` method doesn't do anything by default.  It's there so you can subclass `UIView` and do your own drawing.

In order to draw your view into a context you need to use one of the functions specifically made for that.

In your case you could change `redView.draw(rect)` to:

`redView.drawHierarchy(in: rect, afterScreenUpdates: true)`

There are other methods you could use too, such as this one that uses the view's layer:

```
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

redView.layer.render(in: context)
```